# Spinners not populated with text

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am using a spinner in several places in my program, but I will stick with one case.

I have two xml files -- **small_new_system** and **new_system**.  They both have the a spinner that is named `state_spinner`.

The odd thing is that when I use this code on a tablet running 3.2, which uses new_system, they are displayed but when I put the app on my phone that is running 2.1, which uses small_new_system, they do not show up.  The items are in the spinner list, but there is no text being displayed.  I have tried naming the spinners differently, as well as not using a custom spinner layout.

The other odd thing is that when I use the identical layouts, which do not look very good, on the small device they are not populated with the text either.

Thank you for any help!  My code is as follows:

Code to populate the spinner:

```
states = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.state_spinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter
    .createFromResource(this, R.array.states,
          R.layout.spinner_layout);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
states.setAdapter(adapter);
states.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyItemsOnSelectListener());`
```

Spinner in small_new_system:

```
<Spinner
   android:id="@+id/state_spinner"
   android:layout_width="200dp"
   android:layout_height="55dp"
   android:layout_below="@+id/city_edit"
   android:layout_margin="5dp"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:inputType="textPersonName"
   android:textSize="40dp" >
   </Spinner>
```

Spinner in new_system:

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/state_spinner"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/city_edit"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textSize="60dp" >
</Spinner>`
```

Code in custom spinner:

```
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/spinnerTarget"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textColor="#00000000"
    android:textSize="40dp" >
</TextView>`
```

Comment: I would post an image, but I am not allowed to. . .

Comment: The spinners seem to be correctly populated when I use the emulators for android 3.0 and higher, but not for any of the operating systems in the 2's.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing:

```
android:inputType="textPersonName"
```

from small_new_system. Then it would look like:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/state_spinner"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/city_edit"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textSize="40dp" >
</Spinner>
```

Or you might try adding a background color:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/spinnerTarget"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textColor="#00000000"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:textSize="40dp" />
```

Comment: That did not make a difference.  The spinner list still does not contain any text, but has all of the rows.

Comment: That did not fix it either.  I am wondering if custom spinner layouts are even supported in the early operating systems?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with was to use android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item for my spinner when an sdk less than 11 is detected, and when the sdk is greater than 11 I use my custom spinner.  This seems to work ok.  Not my favorite solution, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one ..

```
spnPlan = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.set_spinner1);

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> planAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.plan_size, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                planAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spnPlan.setAdapter(planAdapter);
        spnPlan.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
```

Comment: This is exactly what i did.  I have determined that the older sdks do not support custom layouts.  Weather or not this is true, I do not know.  See previous answer.